# Split paragraph into sentences

Tags: android

I am developing an app for checking grammatical mistakes by recording the user's voice. I converted the voice into text. Now I want to split the text into sentences. The text does not contain any punctuation marks. Can anyone suggest hoe to split the text into sentences?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! What you can do is parse that string and use regex to split it into the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle different cases for regex. here is a simple example:

Process 1:

```
String text = "First text. Second text.";
String[] sentence = text.split("(?[a-z])\\.\\s+");
```

Process 2: you can also use BreakIterator

```
BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
iterator.setText(text);
int start = iterator.first();
for (int end = iterator.next();
    end != BreakIterator.DONE;
    start = end, end = iterator.next()) {
}
```

Output:

First text.

Second text.

You can also check the language processing tool. For more details visit there:[LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/)